# Use an image in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, compiler-errors, directory

I recently just took a lot of my images from my drawable folder, and put them into an [online image resizer](http://www.picresize.com/), and put them back into the drawable folder. Ever since, I am getting this error:

[image]

This is odd, because the image is actually showing in the design view properly (although its a bit blurry?) but its giving me a compiler error when running. What could the problem be?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try cleaning and rebuilding the project. These kinds of stuff usually happen when you overwrite a previous file with a new file with the same name.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Why are the images blurry though? In the actual image file, it is crystal clear, but on the device, it is blurry!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia It is blurry because it is **scaled**. You should read [how to support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)